# Magento 2 show out of stock configurable product

Tags: magento2

So i have furniture bed configurable product which has 4 simple products "Single | Double | Queen | King" if in the admin panel i set the inventory of "single bed" to 0 then "Single" option is not showing at all, i want is it to show "Single" in the frontend and as Out of Stock... so i can add email option later if available.

I tried "show out out stock items in frontend" but it only works for simple product not configurable

thanks

Answer (score 0):

It might depend on the version you're using of magento if you're using an older one, that I think you are because that's a more or less feature you can try this
https://github.com/interjar/configurable-child-visibility

If you're using a more recent version the should show out of the box with that option. But I must say, in the recent version of magento and without plugins most of the products they show the options even out of stock as intended but some just don't and I can't get why.

Hope it helps :D